# Почему не работает обработчик?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Веду логин и пароль делаю авторизацию и мне выдает неверный логин или пароль хотя указанно все правильно. 
Как мне кажется проблема в том что $data не выдает правильный хеш который есть в бд потому что если убрать хеш и с делать авторизацию без него все работает.
Но если это так я не знаю как это исправить 
Вот скрипт:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {

    $result= $db->prepare('SELECT mail, password FROM accreg WHERE mail=:mail LIMIT 1');
    $result -> bindParam(':mail', $_POST['mail'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result -> execute();
    $data = $result->fetch();
    if(password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        echo 'Все работает';
    }else {
    //неверный логин или пароль
    }
}
```

Comment: А с какой стати $data вообще должна "выдавать" $hash?

Comment: Рабочий пример:  https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash

Comment: Все ровно выдает не правильный логин или пароль( А это может быть еще из-за чего нибудь другого

Comment: а откуда вы в этом коде берете $password и $hash? может $data['password'] имелось в виду? а может в базе данных несколько емайлов идентичных?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749212/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [почему не работает обработчик данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749212/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: @ГусейнАсланов, внесите изменения в этот вопрос, а не создавайте новый.